# Optimizing my code [2d list, accessing every second element of the list]

Tags: python, list, 2d

There is no error in this code, but I want to optimize it. The program returns a new list with all the ages of the students. I think there is a more efficient  way of doing this, do you have any ideas?

```
age_list = [["Sam",14],["Alex",18],["Emil",12]]
ages = []
for i in age_list: ages.append(i[1])
print(ages)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ages = [x[1] for x in age_list]
```

Try list comprehension

Comment: To have a better comprehension about how SO works I suggest you to look at this :https://stackoverflow.com/tour
it will be useful for future questions.